# How do I test my TCP protocol app?

Tags: tcp, xmpp, protocols, network-protocols, instant-messaging

When creating apps that interface on various TCP protocols (apart from HTTP), we need to test our app and how it communicates with a real server.

Now typically with shared hosting you can't install any low level service to talk protocols like POP3, IMAP for email, [SIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_Initiation_Protocol) or [XMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Messaging_and_Presence_Protocol) and for instant messaging.

So are there "test" servers that exist (like example.com) that help you debug or test if you app is speaking that protocol correctly?

Or maybe its easy enough to install some email/IM protocol server on another local PC and then we can use [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to test with that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think wireshark is probably your best bet. I have never heard of publicly available test servers, I would install a server on your LAN and use that for testing.

Comment: Are there any email/IM protocol "servers" that can be installed on Windows XP machines?

Comment: There should be plenty of free or open-source server software for Windows XP unless you're working with very proprietary protocols in niche areas.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Server comes with a built in SMTP server. Try [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323436) for some information

There is a list of XMPP servers [here](http://xmpp.org/software/servers.shtml), I have personally used OpenFire on Windows.